# RSS feed for job listings does not work

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I tried to add the rss feed for job listings into two rss readers and both times it says the feed is not in a correct format.  Can someone look into this?

The link is found at the bottom of job listings.

Comment: We added location a few months back to satisfy [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256521/include-location-and-company-on-careers-rss-feed) request. Looks like it isn't marked as an extension... Fixing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the report - the feed now validates!

Comment: Was this just pushed because its not working for me.

Comment: @JonH https://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fcareers.stackoverflow.com%2Fjobs%2Ffeed works for me

Comment: @JonH although it complains about the location namespace... However, it's only a warning. Which readers are you trying to use?

Comment: It's working now.  Thanks.